# How to re-wire coax through floor

Tags: wiring, coaxial-cable

First, thanks for reading and please know I'm on mobile asking, where I'm not the best at coherency.

I bought a house that has holes to run coax cable through an upstairs wall down to a hole in a closet underneath. This hole is about 3 feet below the ceiling of the closet.

I'm trying to feed coax cable through the hole upstairs down, but am struggling to thread the cable through the downstairs hole.

Most tutorials online are to either install electrical wiring or install plates - neither of which fit my scenario.

Any thoughts? Should I try a bent hanger?

Comment: Why do the wall plates not fit your scenario?  Got a sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By all means try a bent coat hanger. What do you have to lose?

Comment: I can't tell if this is sarcastic or not...I'm pretty sure any wires in the walls would be grounded, but that would be my concern lol

Comment: It **might** work to get some stout string, tie a plastic grocery shopping bag to the end and use a shop vac on the lower hole,.  Feed the bag/w string into the upper hole.  I use this trick all the time, but it's on conduit.   If you have too many air leaks in your route, it probably won't work,  But IMHO, it's worth a try.   You may need to enlarge the holes.

Comment: @EricHorodyski   Coax would not be grounded in the walls.

Comment: @EricHorodyski  Electric wires in a wall will have insulation.  Unless you grind a point on the hanger and start jabbing it into stuff it should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

A basic wire hanger certainly makes for a valid and budget fishing tool. I would suggest however to ignore the coax for the moment and  use whatever fishing tool you come up with and attach some light twine rope. With the twine run through either end of wall/floor then attach the coax to that. The extra step will save a great deal of headache and time while pulling it through.

For any wall outlets I'd recommend using low voltage receptacle boxes. Minimal extra cost for a tidier end product and rather than basic hole and grommet. Would be a good time to run some ethernet also. Even if not needed now will save another headache later.